# Modify the value of a multi-nested dictionary

Tags: python

What is the best way to access a multi-nested dictionary by its value and modify its value? The way that the value is modified must be by its current value. To explain better, the below example array `myArr` has a nested dictionary with value `c2` how can I access that dictionary and modify `c2` into `c2_edit`? The final output should look like `editedArr`. What is the most efficient way to achieve this for a large array size? Thanks in advance

```
myArr = [{
  "a1": [{
    "b1": "c1"
  }, {
    "b2": "c2"
  }]
}, {
  "a2": [{
    "b3": "c3"
  }, {
    "b4": "c4"
  }]
}]

#expected output
editedArr =  myArr = [{
  "a1": [{
    "b1": "c1"
  }, {
    "b2": "c2_edit"
  }]
}, {
  "a2": [{
    "b3": "c3"
  }, {
    "b4": "c4"
  }]
}]
```

Comment: `myArr[0]['a1'][1]['b2'] = 'c2_edit'`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to modify all `dict` values that contain a certain value? If You had `"b3":"c2"`, would it be changed too?

Comment: @tdelaney the way my nested array is generated there wouldn't be any duplicate values so that wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to modify an arbitrarily nested object is generally a recursive function:

```
>>> def recursive_replace(obj, old_value, new_value):
...     if obj == old_value:
...         return new_value
...     if isinstance(obj, dict):
...         return {k: recursive_replace(v, old_value, new_value) for k, v in obj.items()}
...     if isinstance(obj, list):
...         return [recursive_replace(i, old_value, new_value) for i in obj]
...     return obj
...
>>> myArr = [{
...   "a1": [{
...     "b1": "c1"
...   }, {
...     "b2": "c2"
...   }]
... }, {
...   "a2": [{
...     "b3": "c3"
...   }, {
...     "b4": "c4"
...   }]
... }]
>>> recursive_replace(myArr, "c2", "c2_edit")
[{'a1': [{'b1': 'c1'}, {'b2': 'c2_edit'}]}, {'a2': [{'b3': 'c3'}, {'b4': 'c4'}]}]
```

Other types of nested object (tuples, sets, or your own classes) can easily be added as additional `if` blocks in the replacement function.  The important thing is that each recursive call needs to apply the function to the object's contents and return the modified object.

Answer (score 0):

***Pythonic 1-liner function:***

```
def edit_any_value(arr, val, n_val):
    return [{k: [{k: v if v != val else n_val for k, v in nd.items()} for nd in v]} for d in arr for k, v in d.items()]
```

*This doesn't modify the existing array, but it creates a new one with your modificated value.*

I think creating new modified versions of one variable is always better than modifying it, but that's just my opinion!